# can same session key create different login session for every client?

Tags: php, asp.net, session, authentication, session-variables

I create session keys by taking user's unique email or id for creating login sessions

**example:**

```
Session["id"] = email; //where email is unique if user's account is present
```

what if i take same session key for creating login sessions?

```
Session["permanent"] = "stack_overflow";
```

will it do what i asked in the question? i am just curious as i don't know how to run multiple logins on localhost(can i run multiple logins somehow?)

Comment: A session is a way to bind a browser session to a session server side. If you use different browsers (or privacy mode) you should be served a new session.

Comment: @JimL that means every client will get his own login account even if we use  same session keys,as they use different browsers..?

Comment: Yes. the session keys are not shared, they are limited to the current session (user) only